# node/no-unpublished-import: "chai" is not published

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint, chai

I have a [chai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai) among my `devDependencies`:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "4.2.14",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
}
```

Chai is requires for tests only, but I don't going to publish the test files.
The rule [node/no-unpublished-import](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unpublished-import.md) tells me:

```
"chai" is not published
```

From the documentation:

> This intends to prevent "Module Not Found" error after npm publish. 
> If you want to import devDependencies, please write .npmignore or
> "files" field of package.json.

I did not understand what means "write .npmignore" advice. What I need to write there?
Currently, I have below content:

```
.idea/

/.eslintignore
/.eslintrc.yaml
/.gitignore
/.mocharc.yaml
/.npmignore
/tsconfig.json

**.test.ts
```

The last one ignores all test files using chai.

Answer (score 8):

You should add this rule to the `.eslintrc` file:

```
    "node/no-unpublished-import": ["error", {
      "allowModules": ["chai"]
  }]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using require, but the rules are similar:

`.eslintrc`:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "node/no-unpublished-require": ["error", {"devDependencies": true}]
  }
}
```

Comment: The `devDependencies` option does not exist (anymore at leaast). If you want to allow imports from any package listed in your package.json, and not allow importing packages that just so happen to be in your node_modules. Disable `node/no-unpublished-require` and enable `node/no-extraneous-import`. This will let you import devDependencies. Useful if you setup something like webpack.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this worked for me:

In `.eslintrc`

```
"node/no-unpublished-import": ["error", {
    "allowModules": ["chai"]
}]
```

I find it a bit annoying that it can be done in lots of ways while many don't work.

I hope this helps!